# An upper bound related to Binomial distribution

Tags: probability, combinatorics, statistics

In $m$ independent trials, each with probability at least $p$ of success, the probability that there are at most $k$ success, where $k<mp$, is at most
$$\left(\frac{m-mp}{m-k}\right)^{m-k}\left(\frac{mp}{k}\right)^k.$$

This is an argument in a paper with the book *Probabilistic Methods in Combinatorics* as the reference here. However, I can't find a way to get this book or prove this argument by myself. I don't think the book is worth buying just for one argument. Thus I was wondering if people who either have this book or know how to prove it can help me on this argument.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This follows from the optimal exponential inequality applied to the event $[S_m\leqslant k]$, where $S_m$ is binomial $(m,p)$. To wit, for every $r$ in $(0,1)$,
$$
P(S_m\leqslant k)\leqslant r^{-k}E(r^{S_m})=r^{-k}(pr+1-p)^m.
$$
The optimal $r$ is
$$
r=\frac{k(1-p)}{p(m-k)},
$$
which yields the upper bound in the post (*check this!*).

If each trial has probability $\geqslant p$ of success, the total number of successes $T_m$ is such that $T_m\geqslant S_m$ in distribution, hence $P(T_m\leqslant k)\leqslant P(S_m\leqslant k)$. This completes the proof.